# How to get total of 2 arrays

Tags: php, laravel

How do I get the total of 2 arrays.

```
$array1 = [176, 0];
$array2 = [0, 160];

$combinedArrays = $array1 + $array2;

// Actual result
[176, 0]

// Desired result
[176, 160]
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: To make your question more helpful to others, it would be nice if you try to improve it a little bit, even if it has been answered already.

Comment: @Camilo thanks for all the help. What is your suggested question then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
$array1 = [176, 0];
$array2 = [0, 160];
$array3 = array_filter(array_merge($array1,$array2));
print_r($array3);
```

`array_filter` will take the 0 out and `array_merge` will merge 2 arrays together.

You can use

```
$array3 = array_values(array_filter(array_merge($array1,$array2)));
```

to reset the keys.

PHP refer for [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [array_merge](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Thanks. But it will not preserve the keys if I will merge the two arrays.

Comment: use this `$array3 = array_values(array_filter(array_merge($array1,$array2)));`

Comment: The actual output of `$array3` is not `[176, 160]` but `[0 => 176, 3 => 160]`.

Comment: @LongKim What if the arrays are formatted strings? e.g  `$array1 = [176.00, 0.00]; $array2 = [0.00, 160.00];` How can I achieve this output : `[176.00, 160.00]`?